# Haskell. Listas

Tags: haskell

Buenas tardes.
Necesito crear una función en `Haskell` que verifique que varios elementos se encuentran en dicho orden en una lista dada.

Es decir:

`se_encuentra [5,4,7] [1,4,5,4,7,9,10] == True`

`se_encuentra [5,4,7] [1,4,6,6,5,4,0,7] == False`

Lo intentando hacer con `subsequences` (Data.List), pero no funciona como pretendo.

Un cordial saludo.
Muchas gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ver el problemo aqui:

- `isInList :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe [a]` intenta de encuentrar a `x` en `xs` y retorno el resto de la lista (o falla si no puede encuentrar a `x`).
- `se_encuentra :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool` usa multiples veces a `isInList` para encuentra todas las valores en `xs` y controls el resultado final no es `Nothing`

En `se_encuentra` quieres procesar a tu input de izquierda a derecha asi tienes que usar algo como `foldl` y `isInList` puede fallar asi tienes que usar `foldlM` (la monadic version de `foldl`).

En otras palabras (quizas mas comprensible que mi espanol):

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Foldable

isInList :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
isInList x xs = case dropWhile (x /=) xs of
  []         -> Nothing
  (_ : rest) -> Just rest

se_encuentra :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
se_encuentra xs ys = isJust (foldlM (flip isInList) ys xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Con `subsequences` obtienes todas las secuencias posibles de cualquier longitud, incluyendo secuencias que te darían falsos positivos al hacer la comprobación.

Por ejemplo, de `[1,4,6,6,5,4,0,7]` obtienes `[5,4,7]` como secuencia. Necesitas alguna forma de que las secuencias sean de elementos seguidos, sin saltos.

Una forma simple es combinar `isPrefixOf` con `tails`:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf, tails)

contiene :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
contiene xs ys = any (xs `isPrefixOf`) (tails ys)
```

Que se puede hacer más elegante como:

```
contiene :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
contiene xs = any (xs `isPrefixOf`) . tails
```